# Logic parent Exception for TreeView dynamic error

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I built a code that takes data from an online database and adds them recursively through a while loop in a TreeView. Substantially the Add function is called when the user selects a new nation in the tree, for example, this is what is contained in the TreeView (Available countries):

```
<TreeView Name="nation_team" SelectedItemChanged="nation_team_SelectionChanged">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Italy"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Germany"/>    
</TreeView>
```

when the user selects for example Italy, then the following function is set in motion:

```
private void nation_team_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
     soccerSeason.getChampionshipsForTeams();
}
```

the following function contains this content:

```
string stm = @" SELECT * FROM league 
                            WHERE country = '" + MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, database.Connection);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.SelectedValue.ToString() };

while (rdr.Read())
{
      rootNode.Items.Add(getTreeViewChampionships(rdr.GetString(3)));
      MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode);
}

rdr.Close();
```

As you can see I run a query to download all the championships for the nation selected, that is precisely the value taken from the TreeView (Italy or Germany).
Now I run the query and execute the reader "RDR".
Then I declare a rootNode that corresponds to the country selected by the user, in this country you have to add the championships returned from Query, if the user select "Italy", I'm waiting this result structure in TreeView:

```
Italy
   Serie A //this two values was returned by query
   Serie B
```

So far no problem query is successful and the values are read.
At this point it is activated while loop that loops through all the values, inside the while loop we find this method:

```
rootNode.Items.Add(getTreeViewChampionships(rdr.GetString(3)));
```

that would add "Serie A and Serie B" to Italy. The method `getTreeViewChampionships`, the method receives as a parameter the championships they are reading "RDR", in particular "Series A" and "Series B".

```
private TreeViewItem getTreeViewChampionships(string campionato)
{
      TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = campionato };
      return item;
}
```

It would seem that there should be no problems and yet whenever I select a nation comes back the following error on this line:

```
MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode);
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: For the item already exists a logical parent element. You must disassociate it from the old parent before it can bind to a new parent.
>       in MS.Internal.Controls.InnerItemCollectionView.AssertPristineModelChild (Object item)
>       in MS.Internal.Controls.InnerItemCollectionView.Add (Object item)
>       in System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.Add (Object newItem)

What am I doing wrong?

**NB: The Nation available in the XAML is just an example, I add the Nations behind the code, like this way:**

```
TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = rdr.GetStringOrNull(0) };
MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Answer

I managed to reproduce your problem with that minimal code :

```
private void nation_team_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = nation_team.SelectedValue.ToString() };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        rootNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "some data" });
        nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode);
    }
}
```

This is how to resolve your problem :

```
private void nation_team_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem rootNode = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        rootNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "some data" });
    }
}
```

In that code, you won't create a new `TreeViewItem` with the same header as the selected item. You just get the actual selected item (i.e. `e.NewValue`) so you can directly add what you want.

Result on click :

[image]

Hope that helped.

---

### Answer to comment

In order to dissociate root nodes (i.e. countries) and child nodes (i.e. series), I suggest something like that :

```
TreeViewItem rootNode = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue;
if (rootNode.Parent is TreeView)
{
    //Country
}
else
{
    //Serie
}
```

If the parent type is `TreeView`, then the node is a root node and you can get the data from your database. If not, you are on a child node, and you can do other stuff.

---

### Edit after context changed

I can't reproduce your issue. I used an empty `TreeView` in XAML code, then that code-behind :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var rootNode1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Italy" };
    var rootNode2 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Germany" };
    nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode1);
    nation_team.Items.Add(rootNode2);
}

private void nation_team_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem rootNode = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        rootNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "some data" });
    }
}
```

All worked as excepted. `e.NewValue` is not null. Are you sure you are doing it the same way ?

Comment: Very interesting, I would like to ask you a question: I need to download the values for the data in Germany, obviously if I change the selection of the item in the TreeView will activate the same function "nation_team_SelectionChanged", but I need to do, however, different methods. How then can I tell if the user has selected an item Root (Country), a son (ie Series A and Series B), then these will have other children and so on.

Comment: @Bender Please see my edit and tell me if I understood your question.

Comment: If the "e" parameter missing? I doesn't have this variable in any method.. So in particular method I can't do this: TreeViewItem rootNode = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue;

Comment: @Bender You have this variable as a parameter of the event. You can get the `TreeViewItem` in the event and then pass it to other functions.

Comment: Okay, just one problem, this  TreeViewItem rootNode = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue; return null, why? I've the Nation in the TreeView. Maybe because this code get the Nations from the Xaml code? I insert the Nation behind the code not in the XAML, my is just an example in the topic..

Comment: @Bender I honestly have no idea of why. I would need the code you use in order to help. I see no reason

Comment: Please, see my update to check how I add the Nations.

Comment: Of course! I'm using the while(rdr.Read()) because I don't know the number of the values available in the db.

Comment: @Bender If fact, I can't understand how can you have the `SelectionChanged` event fired with `e.NewValue` being `null`. I can't reproduce that, even with adding countries in code behind.

Comment: Yeah, because my query return 0 value, probably MainWindow.AppWindow.nation_team.SelectedValue this is Null and doesn't return the Nation selected